# In C++, can i use structure inside another class?

Tags: c++, oop

I am new to C++ oop and I am skeptical about using structure inside class. if yes, how to get data from it. I've tried searching online but couldn't find an satisfactory answer.

Comment: Yes, you can use a structure inside a class. You use it like you would any other structure. Do you have any specific problem? (Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start reading instead of relying on guessing the right words to search for.)

Comment: `struct Foo { int x; struct Bar { int y; }; };` works just fine.

Comment: You need an instance of the  nested `struct` to get or set data from it. Just declaring a `struct` inside a `struct` does not make an object of the nested struct.

Comment: "how to get data from it" You'd need an instance of your inner struct to get non-static data from. In general, there's no problem with *types* being members of classes

Answer (score 0):

In the answer below each appearance "class" can be replaced with "struct".
This is because in C++ a struct is more or less a class where the default access is "public".

It is not clear from your question what exactly you'd like to do.
Having a class inside a class can have one of the following meanings:

1. Define an inner class  within a class, as a form of "namespacing". Use them both as separate (but related) types.
2. Define an inner class  within a class in order to use it an a type for a member variable.

Example of declaring the classes:

```
class Outer
{
public:
    struct Inner
    {
        int m_ia{ 0 };
        int m_ib{ 0 };
    };
    Inner   m_inner;
};
```

Usage example:

```
int main()
{
    // Usage of the inner class as a separate type:
    Outer::Inner inner;
    inner.m_ia = 333;
    inner.m_ib = 444;

    // Usage of the inner class as a part of the outer class:
    Outer outer;
    outer.m_inner = Outer::Inner{ 111,222 };
}
```

Comment: Hoever if you ever want to use forward declaration of Inner, you are bound to fail.

Comment: I agree. But this is what the OP would like to do (use an inner class).